# Passing abstract class as parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, static

I am trying to set up a class that dynamically builds a filter string.
To do this, i created the following class:

```
export class UrlBuilder<T extends BaseSpalten> {

    private spalten: T;

    ....

    public filterData(config: (spalten: T, addParameter: (key: string, value: string) => void,
        addParameterListe: (key: string, value: string[]) => void) => void): UrlBuilder<T> {
        config(this.spalten, this.addQueryParameter, this.addQueryParamterList);
        return this;
    }

    ....
}
```

But now i have the Problem that the class "BaseSpalten" and the extended classes are static classes:

```
export class BaseSpalten {
    public static AenderungVersion: string = 'AenderungVersion';
    public static Dirty: string = 'Dirty';
}
```

But i need the properties of the classes inside the config function, to ensure i get a valid filter.
How would i pass a reference to the static **T** to the config function?

[Here is a sample Playground link for better understanding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FUpIEICuAlkgCbBQA8AKnKDMAHamZ7rADKYKSDjAfHADeAKBFwJcMFCIA3FAzhpuvJgC441ANxjJUggCMkRBIgiM0MKAQQxoACmU8+G6gEph4vZJgALImgAdE6qjHAAvEoqfDp6AL5iXhJghsamAGYkDFAAIgoo9gjmmQDmGo7R6poANHAopKQACihQKAC2wNnlANbAAJ4aljKMJbXySATAg1ZEIx7hgrIQRKTVSd71TS3tnRQAMgEMPf3Tw6Nw45OnsyUA2gC684vLpE8XL24aOPjEZBQ0glE3kkRUYpXsfgCwUqjFqkKCmwAipMoH1mq0Otk4f4EQ1kRQ0ds2tkDpY3LFgXAoJ0CFAwvCKRIEutpHIFMA6niUYSMbsoPZegMlDMRmMeFdhWcPEDKQB6WVKCAdMzkdbMvSs+SKJHc9HtEmHAUnSU3MUTKYmkYPaXrPTyxUdADCEFV8TEzNAkFgiFQGDgbDQnBhng1qRMwoU4YAgkxyNYRgA1ChoIjma4jCJwADkMeYFAIieTqcYWcZ+iM4cskdMOSIsCFQxumaztfrpZEHvA0HgyHQmCjJS4ziYdBAfBY-vYQ9CIckKQrpirMHDAEkcumSs21+3mYxgAB3bC4QgkOOUAfTvj8ex7w8XmH2NxuQKZVS5fL2CrD2GcrYY2qbHqbSkjAbwyhI9r7r4ChwKQEBwEQcB7sApBwHYUh9mh8HwnA6QFrYxZwvBKAIAgwB+jha5wI0UAQGAFAwH0AD86ygpYCGkJeFqNhmkQhHwgRrjocTkkAA)

Comment: This code doesn't quite constitute a [mcve] and I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. If you need instance properties you should pass in a class instance; if you need static properties you should pass in the constructor itself; if you need both then you should pass both. There are ways to get the constructor from an instance but the typing is annoying and you might have to modify your classes. I'd need a self-contained example to advise more specifically; preferably something that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz hey, thanks for the input, i added a link to a sample, hope this clears up what i mean.

Comment: That link seems to be broken ([sadness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FUpIEICuAlkgCbBQA8AKnKDMAHamZ7rADKYKSDjAfHADeAKBFwJcMFCIA3FAzhpuvJgC441ANxjJUggCMkRBIgiM0MKAQQxoACmU8A23CA))

Comment: @jcalz seems to be working now, sorry for that

Comment: Great, thanks.  I don't see any errors or problems in that code; presumably you want to do something but you can't.  Can your example show some failed attempts so I can see what you're trying to do?  It's not clear to me where you'd like to access the static properties and which properties you want to access.

Comment: @jcalz I updatet the sample once more, so basically I want to be able to pass a reference to the Generic class type and access the static properties of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, we can reduce your question to the following.  Given a class hierarchy with some static properties:

```
class BaseClass {
    public static staticPropBase: string = 'foo';
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    public static staticPropSub: string = 'bar';
}
```

How can we access those static properties from instances of the class?  At runtime this is actually straightforward; all JavaScript objects have a [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) that refers to the constructor function that created it.  So `(new SubClass()).constructor` will be `SubClass`, with all its static properties.

So you can write this and it will work:

```
const subclass = new SubClass();
console.log(subclass.constructor.staticPropBase); // TS error, but "foo" at runtime
console.log(subclass.constructor.staticPropSub);  // TS error, but "bar" at rntime
```

But the problem is that the TypeScript compiler is unhappy.  It does not realize that `subclass.constructor` is the `SubClass` constructor.  All it knows about `subclass.constructor` is that it's a `Function`.  That's true (class constructors *are* functions) but not specific enough to be helpful.

But wait, shouldn't the TypeScript compiler *know* that the type of `(new SubClass()).constructor` is `typeof SubClass` itself?  Yes, probably... and it's [a longstanding open issue, see microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841).  [The stated reason](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841#issuecomment-163350868) why this is not done automatically is that subclass constructors are not required to be valid subtypes of their superclass constructors.  In the following scenario:

```
class A {
    a: string = "a";
    constructor() { } // no param
}

class B extends A {
    b: number;
    constructor(b: number) { // one param 
        super();
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

even though the instance type `B` is a subtype of the instance type `A`, its constructor `typeof B` is *not* a subtype of `typeof A` (because `B`'s constructor requires an argument, while `A`'s does not):

```
const a: A = new B(123); // okay
const _A: typeof A = B; // error! Type 'typeof B' is not assignable to type 'typeof A'.(2322)
```

If the TypeScript compiler automatically gave `A` a `constructor` property of type `typeof A` and `B` a `constructor` property of type `typeof B`, then the instance types `B` would no longer be a valid subtype of `A`, and the `extends` model of subtyping would fail.

Blecch.  It would definitely be nice if TS could do *something* better than `Function`, though.  But even if they eventually make a change, you have your problem *today*.  What can you do now?

---

Probably the best current workaround is to manually declare that your class instances have a `constructor` property of the right type.  Since your class constructors are empty, `typeof SubClass` is a valid subtype of `typeof BaseClass`, so the above problem doesn't come up.  (If it does come up, you could probably use a type like `Pick<typeof SubClass, keyof typeof SubClass>` to keep the static properties but ignore the constructor signature.  More info available upon request.)

The declaration is a little weird, but it looks like this:

```
class BaseClass {
    declare ["constructor"]: typeof BaseClass; // TS 3.7+
    //["constructor"]!: typeof BaseClass; // TS 3.6-
    public static staticPropBase: string = 'foo';
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    declare ["constructor"]: typeof SubClass; // TS 3.7+
    //["constructor"]!: typeof SubClass; // TS 3.6-
    public static staticPropSub: string = 'bar';
}
```

(Note that for TS3.7 and above you should use [a `declare` property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier), whereas for TS2.7 through TS3.6 you should use [a definite assignment assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions).  They basically do the same thing.  More info on request.)

And now the following just works:

```
const subclass = new SubClass();
console.log(subclass.constructor.staticPropBase); // okay, "foo"
console.log(subclass.constructor.staticPropSub);  // okay, "bar"
```

---

Otherwise you can always just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the compiler's warnings:

```
console.log((subclass.constructor as typeof SubClass).staticPropBase); // okay, "foo"
console.log((subclass.constructor as typeof SubClass).staticPropSub);  // okay,  "bar"
```

Personally I'd rather strongly type the class definition, but type assertions will also work.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8AoJMpeHEKKJAIWogGEqajTzOYBXXAS3hIoAFxDCBQ0ePjoMMBlAgAuSWj7AA5kgC8SAOQAzDBj0BuDmQC+pCxVa0AyrxbVaEAB7CIwACa0FzPbsnFy8OBIiYhFSArIwTlgqImqaOvpYIGhmtta28BjAIkK8lK5pwBAA7kgJLjQAFACU5pz5hRh4AHQ4GBr1UCX2nW3J3PDCGGidkdJxAc1IAPSLSAAqDkgQaJhoADRIWNzCSABERhgnSGJIaNzA4pB5BVAdEN29-YOuw8-Ct+OTaYxGSYeK8BZLFbrTbbSb7Q7HE4ZNCXa5oe58R5PdpdHp9T5YUo0H6FP5jCZoK60YQATxgEAwBhqznsjSBURBcnmpkhSAwAGsQDT9mdjCdsS9cR8CUSoCTRgDKdQkLT6YzmVg6lA2TNYqCEhDlnzBcKyEjMpdiMRcqBILAEMgADJ8KD8jAANwSIj4wiOfAKADV-VRxAV2HkggBBYIhMggJJ-dRaXQnEAnFqxii-f4UppEJCWXnADBIOBocA5CNlOibTzePxIaMkTMHFTAbhgLBbDOxkZkxX1RJIdudraNfNGgrIMvgJC2FsDeloJo9lsqgAWLs6WDSWFXnGsB4lx3jjfKVXo9QAjAAmADMC0nJuPSAA+pGVKqGUzo7o6DyjS2HYAEI1jpZA9C-dU6D0JAXWHDATxoPgNFAXBkAmFVwP0KCfz0Tp6nvG8b0aa0rVtaA4EQGoOj9MNm3IWV6EYLUY1jZYfAgUo0GQABtE4+xzSYTgAXU-cDoJY+wAKhDY706AB2ABqedyH4wTyWEkTgPEtUmQCLUZLWOTOgANgAWlUsgeH4QRdTs4E5kYBMUmTfRzmyI8qzYWogg8LxfH8KSygY2NOO4viBOzTSUTErC9I1QzeWheTlKsyF1OixVRJ0+Lv0S6TkpMiz0ps8IHI5SQOTiBIXKTNI9GRTzyFyVpfmKQkgl0Cpql81wVwlV53j6AZOu+DTFXZWZQW5XkBSFEVznFNqcTePEZSGCaKSmvU5ANHk5pNEVkXFa0gA)